# Is the era of Vedas over ? Are revelations in Vedas complete?

Tags: vedas, puranas, sankhya

Indra is the main God of Vedas but he is not worshiped anymore . Krishna stopped his worship . Now the main gods of Hinduism have changed .

[Are the revelations made in Vedas valid anymore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkk8JVuvmCo) ?

Perhaps the revelations in Vedas were not complete that is why Ved Vyas wrote other books like Mahabharata , Purana and Upanishads.

Also Krishna tells in Bhagvad Gita that Vedas are only about three Gunas and asks Arjun to rise above them.

Sankhya which is the central philosophy of Mahabharata, Gita and Puranas was revealed later and is not mentioned in Vedas.

Comment: Ved Vyasa did not write the Upnaishads .. Upanishads don't have any author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is the era of Vedas over?**  After reading the following you make your own conclusion.

**Are revelations in Vedas complete?**
To understand their revelation we have to first answer this question: **In what context can the Vedas be explored?** In Vedas, Rishis (Ṛṣi) use vocabulary in **three variations** based on the context of the hymn. These three variations are - first, the physical level, meaning the material plane of reality where all beings reside this is called adhibhautika; second, the divinity in association to a Deva called adhidaivika; and **finally, the yogic level**, meaning the union with consciousness (cit) called ādhyātmika. Yoga has two layers - the inquisitive layer, like the Vedāntic synopsis, and the mechanics, like the kriyas (actions) used for Sadhana (practice). These mechanics are found both in Śiva Tantras and Patanjali Yoga Sutras.

Now, let's apply a historical context: There were over 1180 Vedic Shakas (call them schools). Today we have only 14, out of them only 6 to 7 are in actual practice, meaning they are transmitted verbally through family lineage. Take note that 98% is lost forever due to invasions. The Gov. Of India has created a portal and has recorded this by inviting these family members. **But didn't our great Rishis foresee this danger?** Yes, a child prodigy at a very young age saw this. This young boy, walked the entire land of Bharat on foot multiple times and re-organized the entire Vedic essence. He collected various Upanishads (Veda+anta = Vedantas) belonging to various Shakas/Schools. Then he added Brahma Sutras and extracted Gita out of Mahabharata Itihasa. Then He took content out of Tantras and created various hymns like Soundarya Lahiri and gave a thesis called Prapancha-Sara-Tantra (The transcendental (Tantric) essence (Sara) of the 5 elemental creation(prapancha)). With this, this young boy before the age of 30 established 4 schools surrounding Bharat. He foresaw the loss of various Vedic Schools and gave this massive collection of literature that is extracted out of Vedic essence. 1000 years later many sectarian acharyas emerged and created their own subset schools specific to the diety of their preference.

From the above, you should have your answer on two fronts, one how this young boy summarized the entire Vedic essence with Upanishads belonging to various sects + Sutras + Gita + Tantra + Bhakti Hymns. Second, how the 3rd Variation (ādhyātmika) became prominent today with Sankhya and Yoga as the modern spiritual methods. Though Yajna may not be widely prominent, its Vedantic end took its place in this modern era for inquisitive minds, whereas Yoga Sutras and Tantra became the mechanical and physical methods of practice.

**What about Vedic Devas?** the entire land of Bharath if you explore without sectarian mind you will see Rudra's associated temples from Kedarnath to Kanyakumari to Rameshwaram. Rudra is a Vedic concept belonging to Rta, whereas Shankara is the personification of this concept, and the Linga worship became the prominent aspect of his worship. Not just by humans but every legend of History, including Devatas, Rishis, Avatars, Pandavas, Asuras all established Linga across this land. This doesn't mean the other 2 Trimurtis are of less significance. Lord Vishnu worship took the shape of Role Model rather than Idol-based worship. Hence Ramayana and Mahabarata became this land's History and both Rama, Parashurama, Krishna, and Venkateshwara became living examples of today's generation.

**What about other Vedic Devas?** Rudra is a Vishvaroopa concept, meaning a concept that encompasses many subconcepts in Veda. For example, Agni, Vayu, Soma, Yama, Ashvinis are all called Rudras. So the concept of Rudra overlapped over many other Divinities in Vedas. Vishnu became the charismatic and charming personification of all the Adityas including Indra and Surya under the umbrella concept called Narayana. Both Became the Supreme Purushas of Vedas. Yes, individual fame might not be seen to Indra or Agni, but they were merged into 3 Murties called Trimurti. Lord Brahma became the embodiment of Prajapati.

Even after all this, the Sanatana literature is so vast that people are still quarreling with each other to proclaim their fan-club sect is supreme compared to the other. Whereas the Buddhists, Yogis and Tantrics are busy indulging in Yogic and meditative practices and enhancing their life energies and consciousness.